# Add new MenuItem from AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, menu, android-actionbar

I have an ActionBar with different MenuItems and I want to add a new MenuItem but only if a flag is set to true. I receive the value for this flag from a web service - using an AsyncTask.

In my activity I tried to get a global reference to the Menu:

```
public class EventProgramFragmentActivity extends BaseRoboSherlockFragmentActivity {
    Menu activityMenu;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    this.activityMenu= menu;
    ...
}
```

and use the activityMenu in onPostExecute but I get a Null Pointer Exception in onPostExecute  and I think it's - because onCreateOptionsMenu is called after onCreate is finished -  so the activityMenu is null. (the AsynkTask is executed in onCreate)

So how should I add a new MenuItem - after the AsynkTask fetches the flag?

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing inflating the menu before assigning it?

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
     this.activityMenu= menu;
    ...
}
```

Comment: No - I don't use a XML menu layout to define my menu. I add the menu items dynamicaly

Comment: Please provide code, where and how you create menu at runtime.